# Proof that Dandelin sphere is focus of the parabola

Tags: calculus, geometry, conic-sections, spheres

Suppose a plane intersects a right-circular cone in a parabola with vertex at V: Suppose that a sphere is inscribed between the cone and the plane as in the previous exercises and is tangent to the plane of the parabola at point F:

Show that the chord to the parabola through F that is perpendicular to F V has length equal to that of the latus rectum of the parabola.Therefore, F is the focus of the parabola.

I know that the semi latus rectum of parabola should be twice as long compared to line from focus to vertex but i couldn't come up with a way proves that.

[image]

I'm a chemical engineer graduate, trying to learn math from scratch.

Edit:
Solution of previous exercise, a classic proof:

Since tangents from a outer point to a sphere have same length.

$PB=PF_2$ and $PA=PF_1$

$PB+PA=PF_2+PF_1= AB = \ \text{constant}$

proving $F_1$ and $F_2$ are focal points.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: "as in the previous exercise" - *what* previous exercise?

Comment: Previous excercise of dandelin sphere way of proving tangent of two distinct sphere inside of conic  touching the ellipse from its focal point. I will add the image of solution of previous exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
PF=PM=BT=2BV=2VF.
$$

[image]

[This space intentionally left blank]

Comment: Beautifully visualized.